Female prisoner is transferred to spacestation invaded by an alien
Woman is transferred from a prison colony planet to a space station where the scientist in charge is some sort of sex researcher I believe?  Prisoner falls for a male worker on the station who later sacrifices himself to save her after an alien invades the ship.  There was a chest bursting scene when the baby alien was born. I think there might have been slow motion blood.  It was clearly a huge rip of Alien, and I am trying desperately to remember the name of it.

You might check out the list of films under "Referenced In" and "Spoofed In" at Alien's IMDb Connections page.

Quite possibly Lethal Target from 1999. An 'Alien' rip-off about a woman in a prison colony sent to a space station where a doctor experiments with women. Alien infections and alien-fighting ensue.
